# Flutter Duration Picker Package

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-widget

I’m having trouble with the Flutter Duration Picker Package.

Basically I just want to show their Duration Picker via showDurationPicker function. Without using Duration Picker as a child like in the example.
Possible or other Solutions? I want to let the User select a time for a Countdowntimer.

Package:
https://pub.dev/packages/duration_picker

**Here's the Code:**

```
                       IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.history_rounded,
                              color: AppTheme.blue,
                              size:
                                  3.23 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier //30.0,
                              ),
                          onPressed: ()  {
                            Duration _durationResult =
                                await 
                                showDurationPicker(
                                    snapToMins: 5.0,
                                    context: context,
                                    initialTime: Duration(
                                        hours: 2,
                                        minutes: 0,
                                        seconds: 0,
                                        milliseconds: 0));

                                        
                            
                          }),
```

**Terminal:**

Xcode's output:

↳
../../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_duration_picker-1.0.4/lib/flutte
r_duration_picker.dart:506:44: Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'.
final Widget actions = new ButtonTheme.bar(
^^^

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code 
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on Xs.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to the new maintained version - https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/duration_picker

Comment: "barely maintained" version, that is